# Setting a cookie using JavaFX's WebEngine/WebView

Tags: cookies, http-headers, javafx-2, javafx, httprequest

I cannot seem to find any way to set a cookie programatically using [WebEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) / [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) in JavaFX. The API doesn't give any idea as to how to obtain an HttpRequest-like object to modify the headers (which is what I use in the app for XML-RPC), or any sort of cookie manager.

No questions on this page seem to touch on the issue either - there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316444/javafx2-0-webview-not-rendering-the-page) but it just disables cookies when in applet to fix a [bug](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-15676), my app is on desktop btw.

The only way I image I could do it is by requesting the first page (which requires a cookie with a sessionID to load properly), getting an "access denied"-style message, executing some javascript in the page context which sets the cookie and then refreshing. This solution would be a horrible user experience though.

How do I set a cookie using WebEngine?

---

**Update:** Taking a clue from a question linked above, I tried digging around for some examples of using [CookieManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/CookieManager.html) and related APIs. [I found this code](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/UsingCookieStore.htm), which I then tried to incorporate into my app, with weird results;

```
MyCookieStore cookie_store = new MyCookieStore();
CookieManager cookie_manager = new CookieManager(cookie_store, new MyCookiePolicy());
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookie_manager);
WebView wv = new WebView();
```

Now lets say we do this:

```
String url = "http://www.google.com/";
wv.getEngine.go(url);
```

Debugging in Eclipse after this request has been made shows that the cookie store map holds a cookie:

```
{http://www.google.com/=[NID=67=XWOQNK5VeRGEIEovNQhKsQZ5-laDaFXkzHci_uEI_UrFFkq_1d6kC-4Xg7SLSB8ZZVDjTUqJC_ot8vaVfX4ZllJ2SHEYaPnXmbq8NZVotgoQ372eU8NCIa_7X7uGl8GS, PREF=ID=6505d5000db18c8c:FF=0:TM=1358526181:LM=1358526181:S=Nzb5yzBzXiKPLk48]}
```

### THAT IS AWESOME

WebEngine simply uses the underlying registered cookie engine! But wait, is it really? Lets try adding a cookie, prior to making the request...

```
cookie_store.add(new URL(url).toURI(), new HttpCookie("testCookieKey", "testCookieValue"));
```

Then I look at the request in Wireshark...

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/535.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) JavaFX/2.2 Safari/535.14
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Host: www.google.com
Connection: keep-alive
```

No cookie for me :(

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I have managed to solve this issue with the help of Vasiliy Baranov from Oracle. Vasiliy wrote to me:

> Try putting the cookie into `java.net.CookieHandler.getDefault()` after
>   the WebView is instantiated for the first time and before the call to
>   `WebEngine.load`, e.g. as follows:

```
WebView webView = new WebView();
URI uri = URI.create("http://mysite.com");
Map<String, List<String>> headers = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
headers.put("Set-Cookie", Arrays.asList("name=value"));
java.net.CookieHandler.getDefault().put(uri, headers);
webView.getEngine().load("http://mysite.com");
```

This will place the cookie into the store permanently, it should be sent out on every subsequent request (presumably provided that the server doesn't unset it).

Vasiliy also explained that `WebView` will install it's own implementation of the `CookieHandler`, while retaining cookies put into the default one.

Lastly, he mentions something quite intriguing:

> Do not waste your time trying to use `java.net.CookieManager`, and
>   `java.net.CookieStore`. They are likely to cause problems with many
>   sites because they implement the wrong standard.

I tried googling after this but it doesn't seem to be common knowledge. If anyone is able to provide more details I would be grateful. It seems weird, since it seems `CookieStore` and `CookieManager` are used by a lot of software out there.

Comment: When i use this code i am getting the bellow exception,

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.net.CookieManager.put() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.util.LinkedHashMap)

Comment: Worked for me thanks a lot! Basically, when the program exits I read the cookies using `cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies()`, save them in a file and use your code at startup to set them.

Comment: @MinasMina when I run `cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies()` I get a blank list.

Answer (score 2):

Solution for java.net.CookieManager

Cookies serialization:

```
        List<HttpCookie> httpCookies = cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        String jsonCookie = gson.toJson(httpCookies);
```

Cookies deserialization:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
List<HttpCookie> httpCookies = new ArrayList<>();
Type type = new TypeToken<List<HttpCookie>>() {}.getType();
httpCookies = gson.fromJson(json, type);   // convert json string to list
for (HttpCookie cookie : httpCookies) {
    cookieManager.getCookieStore().add(URI.create(cookie.getDomain()), cookie);
}
```

Comment: This was the only solution I could get working over the course of the past few days. Such an absurdly simple solution that I overlooked it for far too long. The *only* concern I haven't handled yet is this causes some warnings for "Illegal reflective access by com.google.gson.internal.reflect.UnsafeReflectionAccessor". I'm fighting through Java 12 though, so I know it's extra picky.