# JavaFX Separate Sessions / Cookies

Tags: java, session, cookies, javafx

I'm quite new to Java and JavaFX and as such I think I'm a bit out of my depth.

I've got a basic application at the moment that houses two WebViews `view1` and `view2`, each using a separate WebEngine `engine1` and `engine2`. What I'd hoped was that by using different WebEngines I would be given separate sessions between them, not shared.

Put simply, I'd like to log into the same domain with two different accounts in one Window.

I've had a play with `java.net.CookieManager` and `java.net.CookieHandler` but I don't quite think I'm barking up the right tree with those.

As far as I can find in the JavaFX documentation I can seem to find any sort of Web Session Provider / Handler like there is in some tools like Awesomium/Visual Studio. I'm hoping someone can either tell me the right place to look for such a class or possibly help me to make one.

Application code is as follows, all help is much appreciated

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        //Create a GridPane for browser panes
        GridPane browserGrid = new GridPane();
        browserGrid.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        browserGrid.setPrefSize(primaryStage.getWidth(), primaryStage.getHeight());

        browserGrid.setHgap(10);
        browserGrid.setVgap(10);
        browserGrid.setPadding(new Insets(0, 10, 0, 10));

        java.net.CookieManager manager1 = new java.net.CookieManager();
        java.net.CookieHandler.setDefault(manager1);

        WebView view1 = new WebView();
        WebEngine engine1 = view1.getEngine();

        WebView view2 = new WebView();
        WebEngine engine2 = view2.getEngine();


        engine1.load("https://www.facebook.com");
        engine2.load("https://www.facebook.com");

        browserGrid.add(view1, 0, 1);
        browserGrid.add(view2, 1, 1);


        //playerGrid.setGridLinesVisible(true); 
        Scene scene = new Scene(browserGrid, 1600, 800);  
        primaryStage.setTitle("MultiPane Browser"); 
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); 
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

Just using Facebook as the default site to log in to for the sake of testing

Comment: Maybe this helps you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385233/setting-a-cookie-using-javafxs-webengine-webview
It states, that WebEngine is using an own implementation of CookieHandler.

Comment: I did run across this and it explained a few things, but I can't really see how I can create independent CookieHandlers for each engine/view