# JAVAFX WebView / WebEngine How enable Cookies?

Tags: java, cookies, webview, javafx, javafx-webengine

I don't know how enable cookies on WebView / WebEngine in JAVAFX.
I've found this [Setting a cookie using JavaFX's WebEngine/WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385233/setting-a-cookie-using-javafxs-webengine-webview), but it doesn't work or I don't understand how use it.

How can I enable cookies for my PHP session on my JAVAFX Browser? Is it possible?