# Javafx WebEngine read secured cookies

Tags: javascript, java, cookies, javafx

i need to read and write, secured and unsecured cookies from the JavaFx WebEngine.

I lost the whole day on this problem and tried the following ways:

- Get the cookies from the cookie store -> here I only get cookies without the secured flag. For more information about that I have this issue: [Setting a cookie using JavaFX's WebEngine/WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385233/setting-a-cookie-using-javafxs-webengine-webview)

  - Try to get the cookies over a self written cookie store -> same issue
  - Try to get the cookies with javascript -> restricted through security restrictions
  - Try to get the cookies from the WebEngine dom -> no result

  I hope someone can help me...

Answer (score 3):

Okay,

if everybody have the same Issue, here is the solution:

The function get(URI) from the cookie store is broken and delivers only cookies where the secure flag is false.

**This is not working:**

```
for(URI uri : manager.getCookieStore().getURIs()) {
    for(HttpCookie httpCookie : manager.getCookieStore().get(uri)) {
        System.out.println("test> " + uri.toASCIIString() + " # " + httpCookie.toString() + " - "+httpCookie.getSecure());
    }
}
```

**This is working:**

```
for(HttpCookie httpCookie : manager.getCookieStore().get(uri)) {
    System.out.println("test> " + " # " + httpCookie.toString() + " - "+httpCookie.getSecure());
}
```

If you need the URI for a specific cookie, you have to create it from the HttpCookie.getDomain() getter.