# How to set value in LocalStorage of WebView JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, webview, webengine

I'm trying to save some values in the LocalStorage of WebView of JavaFX. Is it supported by WebView? About html5test.com, the LocalStorage is enabled, but I don't find any solution to save data with Javascript in the LocalStorage.

Comment: AFAIK 'coockies' (which the local storage basically is) and the javafx webview (or java in general) are not a perfect combination. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45827482/access-all-the-cookies-from-a-javafx-webview) for example. Unfortunatly there are many more simular questions both related and unrelated to the javafx webview, all without a good solution or workaround.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
JSObject js = (JSObject)webEngine.executeScript("localStorage");
```

for example, in local storage, we have refreshTime with the value 1000.

**for getting**

```
println(js.getMember("refreshTime")) // print 1000
```

**for setting**

```
js.setMember("refreshTime",2000)
```

JSObject from **import netscape.javascript.JSObject;**

Answer (score 0):

using scripts below could achieve the goal.

```js
function defineProperty(obj, field, newValue, writable = true) {
        Object.defineProperty(obj, field, {
            writable: writable,
            value: newValue,
        });
    }

    var localStorageMock = function () {
        const obj = {};
        return {
            getItem: function (key) {
                let value = obj[key];
                if (value === undefined)
                    return null;
                else
                    return obj[key] + "";
            },
            setItem: function (key, value) {
                obj[key] = value;
            },
            removeItem: function (key) {
                delete obj[key];
            },
            clear: function () {
                Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => delete obj[key]);
            },
            getKeys: function () {
                return Object.keys(obj);
            },
            getValues: function () {
                return Object.values(obj);
            }

        }

    }

 defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', localStorageMock(), false);
//do some test
 window.localStorage.setItem("a",110);
 console.log("window.localStorage.getItem('a')"+window.localStorage.getItem('a'));
```