# Always accept cookies in JavaFX Webview Application

Tags: java, javafx, cookies, webview, instagram

## Hi guys

I am new at JavaFX and now I need some of your help

I made an application and now I need to link my/our instagram profiles for the credits.

I used following code to load the profiles into the webview:

`webview.getEngine().load("https://www.instagram.com/username");`

### Problem 1:

The problem now is, that when the webview loads the instagram page there is a window where I need to accept the cookies, what doesn't work

### Problem 2:

The second question is how to load the instagram page without logging in to my insta profile so that everybody can see it without creating any account.

**Thank's for every help!**

Comment: I’m not on Instagram, but… I don’t think your second problem has any solution.

Comment: Please ask one question per question.  If you have two questions, you have two questions.

Comment: See also [_Access all the cookies from a JavaFX WebView_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45827482/230513).

Comment: There is some information on JavaFX and cookie handling in the answer to [JavaFX webview doesn't save cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48251340/javafx-webview-doesnt-save-cookies). I don't know if that will assist you or not.