# JavaFX WebView - Website won't load (illegal cookie)

Tags: java, webview, javafx, java-8

So i'm trying to load a url into a WebView and i get an exception that thecookie is illegal.
when i looked into the cookie i saw the name of the cookie was empty, and the value was deleted/ and expiry date set to 1970. what is going on here? is this a bug?

and here is the error:

```
Oct 17, 2014 1:14:02 AM com.sun.webpane.webkit.network.URLLoader doRun
```

WARNING: Unexpected error
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal cookie name

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFX2.0 webview not rendering the page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316444/javafx2-0-webview-not-rendering-the-page)

Comment: the solution suggested in the link (setting default cookie handler) doesn't work.

Comment: Then please provide code samples to help someone more fully understand your problem.

Comment: The [Java bug database shows a similar issue](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7183292), however that was fixed long ago.  As the tags to your question show you are using Java8, the linked bug is probably not the cause of the issue you are seeing.

Comment: I'm using JDK1.8, the code is just the simple load method ofWebEngine. This website doesn't load:usautoparts.net  . When I load other websites, 99% of them work good. this specific website loads in all the browsers I checked (IE/FF/Chrome). When I try to load it using WebView i get the illegal cookie error. And no, i don't think the problem is with this specific website..